# To prove that the Cantor function maps the end points of the intervals removed to a same point

Tags: real-analysis, decimal-expansion, cantor-set

For the function f in 1.6D i.e. $$x=0.b_1b_2....(3)$$ then
$$f(x) = y= 0.a_1a_2.....(2)$$ where $a_i=b_i/2$

Here (2),(3) represents the binary and ternary expansions of $x$ respectively.

Show that if $(a,b)$ is any one of the open intervals removed in the construction $K$, show that $f(a)=f(b)$.

Hint: show that a and b can be written $a=0.a_1a_2.....a_n1$, $b=0.a_1a_2.....a_n2$, where each $a_i$ is 0 or 2. Then rewrite the expansion for a using only 0 and 2.

I'm able to prove this for the first interval that is removed $(1/3,2/3)$ but for general case i don't totally get it. How can i able to express $a$ and $b$ in the form given in the hint? I'm lost!! Please help me understand decimal expansion.

Comment: using $b_1,b_2, \ldots$ and $a_1,a_2, \ldots$ for the ternary and binary digits of $x$ and $f(x)$ and then $(a,b)$ for the removed interval may be confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially at each step you are removing the interval between the ternary numbers

- $0.b_1b_2\ldots b_n02222\ldots_3$
- $0.b_1b_2\ldots b_n20000\ldots_3$

with each $b_i \in \{0,2\}$.  The first could also be written as $0.b_1b_2\ldots b_n10000\ldots_3$ and the second as $0.b_1b_2\ldots b_n12222\ldots_3$ but we need to avoid the digit $1$ if we want to apply the function by dividing by $2$.

Applying the function $f$ to these two end points would give

- $0.a_1a_2\ldots a_n01111\ldots_2$
- $0.a_1a_2\ldots a_n10000\ldots_2$

and these are the same value in binary.

Consider the interval $\left(\frac{7}{27}, \frac{8}{27}\right)$ which you will remove.  You can write $\frac{7}{27}$ in ternary as $0.021_3$ i.e. $0.0210000\ldots_3$ but in this case we want to write it as $0.0202222\ldots_3$  so we can divide each digit by $2$ to get $f\left(\frac{7}{27}\right)=0.0101111\ldots_2 = \frac{3}{8}$.   Meanwhile $\frac{8}{27}$ is $0.0220000\ldots_3$ so $f\left(\frac{8}{27}\right)=0.0110000\ldots_2 = \frac{3}{8}$ too.

Comment: how are u saying that the intervals.removed are between those two numbers that you've mentioned? And i don't get the hint given in the book what about it?? There is a 1 in the ternary expansion of a what should i do about it?

Comment: @LakshmiPriya Yes: each removed interval is between a pair of numbers of that ternary form, and every pair of numbers of that ternary form has the interval between them removed.

Comment: @LakshmiPriya If $a$ is the endpoint of a removed interval and has a ternary digit $1$, then you will be able to rewrite $a$ so it does not have a ternary digit $1$.  I have added an example to my answer

Comment: I understand it now. We should rewrite the endpoint to the desired form to apply f. Thanks for the help